# Parse push notifications and iOS 8.2's alert titles

Tags: ios, parse-platform

iOS 8.2 introduced an alertTitle property for remote and local notifications. Is there any way to add the alert title to a Parse push notification? I tried adding both `title` and `alertTitle` to the `data` dictionary, but neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out - instead of passing a string to the `alert` property, send a dictionary with `title` and `body`.

Comment: This looks absolutely horrible in android if you don't explicitly handle the hash serialization.